# performance - read huge FASTA file line by line in C

Tags: c, performance, file, fasta

I have a FASTA file that contain sequence strings upto 2000000 strings [lines]. I wrote the code that works well with smaller size but when the size of file grows it get slower (Even slower then the smaller size file speed). I am confused that why it take more time when file size let see is 100,000 even for first iteration that run very efficiently in case of 10,000.
For Example: I put printf statement for each iteration. In case of 10,000 first iteration take 2 ms. where as in case of 100000 strings even the first iteration will take more time then 2 ms to print and so on. Why it could be slow like that?

Can you please help me how I can make it efficient or even work at the same speed as it do with smaller size file? I am reading it line by line.
My code is

```
    #include "kseq.h"
    KSEQ_INIT(gzFile, gzread)


   int z=0;
    fp = gzopen(dbFile, "r");   //Read database Fasta file into host memory
    seq_d = kseq_init(fp);
    while ((d = kseq_read(seq_d)) >= 0) {
            unsigned char *b = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 256);

            memcpy(b, seq_d->seq.s, 256);
    ....
    do work with b
     ....
     ............
     z++
     free(b);
    }
    kseq_destroy(seq_d);
    gzclose(fp);
```

Comment: The kind of scaling behavior you describe is plausible, but the code fragments you've presented do not explain it.  You'll need to present a [mcve] if you want our help in sorting out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. I didn't notice before but in my code there were two loops that actually run to the size of file and don't needed (That,s why I got the variable time for each iteration too). I just eliminate them and now it work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

to improve the speed you can also move the malloc line before the 'while', and the free after the end of the 'while'.